# Layout similar to Appear.in

Tags: javascript, css, layout, grid

Is there a library or some example out there to create a dynamic layout (group call style) similar to the one used in https://appear.in ?

Edit: I've already tried a "flexbox" solution. It doesn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/868997/max-square-size-for-unknown-number-inside-rectangle) question about maximizing squares in a rectangle.

> You can compute an (optimistic) upper bound by dividing the total surface by the number of squares: `sqrt(width*height/n)`.